# How to find the index of the first char of a substring of string?

Tags: c#, string, substring

I have string like "Helloworld"
and a substring of that like "world"
now , how can I find the index of the first char of the substring in the main string ?
in this case I want the index of 'w' in "Helloworld"

can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Take a look at [string.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Have you considered.. `.IndexOf("world")`?

Comment: [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx) is the first match in google if i enter your title there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to use the [string.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but specifically the overload that accepts the [StringComparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enum

```
string test = "HelloWorld";  // World in uppercase 
int pos = test.IndexOf("world", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
Console.WriteLine(pos.ToString());
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the best answer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var index = "Helloworld".IndexOf("world");
```

will return 5

Answer (score 1):

```
"Helloworld".IndexOf("world");
```

Comment: @Mehdi Np, btw Steve answer should be the accepted one, that is the way to do it.